# How to make the index work for the query with PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, postgis

There is table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dbo.gps_online_state
(
    accountid integer NOT NULL,
    lat double precision,
    lng double precision,
    updatedon timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
);
```

I make sql that search all points in circle with radius 1500 m. But index in that query does not work

```
SELECT * 
from gps_online_state gps
where   gps.lat <> 'NaN' and gps.lng <> 'NaN'
        AND
        gps.updatedon > now() - '1 minute'::interval
        AND
        ST_Contains(
            geometry(
                ST_Buffer(geography(
                     'SRID=4326;POINT(' || 82.599620::text ||' ' || 49.957620::text ||')'), 
                1500)
            ), 
            ST_SetSRID( ST_MakePoint(gps.lng, gps.lat),4326) 
       )
```

Index query:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_gps_online_state_point_updatedon2
   ON dbo.gps_online_state USING gist
   ((st_setsrid(st_makepoint(lng, lat), 4326)::geography), updatedon)
   TABLESPACE pg_default
   WHERE lat <> 'NaN'::double precision AND lng <> 'NaN'::double precision;
```

And I cant to force to work it. Trying geography and geomtry. Nothing help

Comment: Works for me.  What versions are you using?

Comment: @jjanes postgis 2.4.3, PostgreSQL 10.6

Answer (score 1):

I can't find anything as old as 2.4.3 to test with, but if I go back to 2.5.5 in PG 10.18 (using PGDG apt repo), I can get it to work as long as I leave the `::geography` out of the index definition.  Is leaving it out incorrect for some reason?  If so, can you explain why or provide an example to demonstrate the error?

You also have a problem with the other column in the index.  Your column is a timestamp but your computed value is a timestamptz, and this mismatch will prevent it from using that operator from the index.